# Scrapy Python Web Scraping - creating XPath

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to create "universal" Xpath, so when I run spider, it will be able to download the hotel name for each hotel on the list.

This is the XPath that I need to convert:

```
//*[@id="offerPage"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/h3/a
```

Can anyone point me the right direction?

This is the example how they did it in the scrapy docs:

https://github.com/scrapy/quotesbot/blob/master/quotesbot/spiders/toscrape-xpath.py

for text: they have :

```
'text': quote.xpath('./span[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first(),
```

When you open "http://quotes.toscrape.com/" and copy Xpath for text you will get :

```
/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]
```

Comment: In a universal XPath, you cannot use indexes because the order and number of nodes (div in your case) can change from page to page. You have to identify the right blocks exactly by particular attributes. It can be easy if you try to get hotel names from a particular website like booking.com, hotels.com etc. However, if you want to get it working on any website in the internet it is much complicated if possible at all.

Comment: It's almost always for simple things to use CSS selectors instead... try to see if your h3/a elements have a unique class/identifier to work with, so you can do something like: `response.css('#offerPage h3 a')` or similar...

Comment: thanks! How can I add class id to css selector? I tried something like below: print(response.css('#offerPage h3 a [@class = "notranslate]'))

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the html that your are scraping just using "copy xpath" from the browser source viewer is not enough.

You need to look at the attributes that the html tags have.

Of course, using just tag types as an xpath can work, but what if not every page you are going to scrape follows that pattern?

The Scrapy example you are using uses the `span`'s `class` attribute to precisely point to the target tag.

[image: class attribute's value used to locate target data]

I suggest reading a bit more about Xpath ([for example here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)) to understand how flexible your search patterns can be.

If you want to go even broader, reading about DOM structure will also be useful. Let us know if you need more pointers.

Comment: Shall I refer to the class named "notranslate"?

<a href=".." title=".." target="_blank" class="notranslate">Hotel Name</a>

Comment: @luuu since you haven't provided any of the html that you are trying to parse, the only answer I can give you is "that may work". The question you need to ask yourself is "do all `a` tags that I need have the `notranslate` class?"